# Build a client that gets information about projects hosted on a team foundation server

Tags: rest, tfs

I need to build a client application that connects to the team foundation server and retrieves information about the current active projects.

How should I approach this? Does TFS have a built-in REST webservice that exposes this information? Or do I have to create a server component as well using some tfs sdk?

Client will be written in javascript.

Did some research myself but couldn't find anything relevant regarding this, so maybe someone who worked on a similar project could provide some helpful information.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TFS has soap endpoints.  Fire up fiddler while you do stuff in TFS and you will see.

Comment: The Soap endpoint are officially unsupported. Instead, use the Client Object Model to build your own services, or use the recently released OData services for TFS. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13576 (2010) / http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36230 (2012).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TFS SDK to achive this. 
1. Instructions on where to download and how to connect to TFS programmatically http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/18/tfs-2010-sdk-connecting-to-tfs-2010-programmaticallyndashpart-1.aspx

1. Once connected, you can get all active (not deleted) projects by using the following code,
   You can use the IteamProjectCollectionService to perform various collection level operations, such as delete/create projects, etc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.iteamprojectcollectionservice.aspx

   var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(@"TheTfsUrl"));
           var versionControl = tfs.GetService'<'ITeamProjectCollectionService'>'();
2. Loop through each of the projects and you have the following information available.
   Alternatively you can use the VersionControlService to get all projects and loop through each project to get the information

   var version = tfs.GetService'<'VersionControlServer'>'();
           var projects = version.GetAllTeamProjects(true);

   ```
       foreach (TeamProject p in projects)
       {

       }
   ```

Team Project object => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.teamproject.aspx

HTH.

Cheers, Tarun

Comment: Thanks but I need to use javascript. TFS SDK is for visual studio.